# How do I get the long-form instance_id for an App Engine instance?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I can get a short integer instance_id for a running process by calling `modules.get_current_instance_id()`, but this returns an integer index into the list of instances for the current version of the application. I can make an rpc to get the full hex instance_id like this:

```
from google.appengine.api.app_identity import app_identity
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = build('appengine', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
appsId = app_identity.get_application_id()

rpc_result = service.apps().services().versions().instances().list(versionsId='23', servicesId='default', appsId=appsId).execute()

print rpc_result['instances'][int(modules.get_current_instance_id())]
```

This gives me a dict which contains, among other things, an `'id'` key-value pair where the value looks something like this: `00c61b117cb3c50973d6a73225b3d807eb8e873e96abc59c46ebba168897b8dbd9a443af962df5`

This is what I need.

There are two obvious drawbacks of this method. The first is that I'm doing an RPC to get something that must be locally available - somewhere.  The second is the fact that there's a race condition. If `modules.get_current_instance_id()` returns, say, a 3, but instance #2 shuts down between the assignment of that index to this process and when I get the rpc response, I'm going to be off by one in my indexing of the `rpc_result`.

How do I get at this ID in app engine?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it from the INSTANCE_ID environment variable.

You can get it with:

```
os.eniron["INSTANCE_ID"]
```